# webpack-cli SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(\p{Uppercase_Letter}+|\p{Lowercase_Letter}|\d)(\p{Uppercase_Letter}+)/:

Tags: regex, webpack, webpack-cli

I'm trying to install the lastest version of webpack and the following message keeps coming back in my terminal.

[Screenshot after "npm start"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4PU1.png)

Comment: no unfortunately i tried that and it didnt work

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately no i think io abandoned the project srry